# Several error encountered on new update for Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps

Since API 19 was out, I had problems on doing the Google Map on my app. I followed the tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start). I was able to load the map, however a lot of problems surprised me.

```
 map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
```

It does not show anything, just brown tiles. Also, the map does not load all possible views. When I zoom in, it's still blurry.

[image]

As you can see, some of the parts of the map does not load. However long I wait, **IT DOES NOT LOAD**.

I tried to locate myself. [image]

Same result. Maybe two months ago(Still api 18) I created a map too.

[image]

All street names are loaded. Can you please pinpoint what am I doing wrong. If you need my code, tell me. Thanks!

**MY CODE**

```
public class QuezonCityMap extends Activity {
GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quezon_city_map);

    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Sydney")
            .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
            .position(sydney));
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (map == null) {
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                            .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (map != null) {
            // The Map is verified. It is now safe to manipulate the map.

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: is your connection slow?

Comment: that was my first assumption. however, I tried to watch videos in youtube with my s4 and the vids loaded fast.

Comment: you are initializing map twice. also you are not checking the availability of google play services before initializing map.

Comment: I didn't call `setUpMapIfNeeded`, still not working. I have downloaded google play services

Comment: you have called i see that in your code. secondly you have not checked the availability of google play services. http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html. Also if it still slow i guess its the internet speed.

Comment: I mean I already removed it. Still not working.

Comment: I think its not the internet speed. I can use the google maps app in my phone, its functioning well.

Comment: Try to use SupportMapFragment in place of MapFragment.

Comment: I finally solved it. I forgot that I'm using a release keystore. I use usb debugging on my phone and its not running the whole time. What a silly mistake. :)